# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Identificacion' to data type int

Tags: sql

Tengo dos problemas con mi código al intentar ejecutar se presentan estos errores.

El primero es este

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Identificacion' to data type int."

El segundo es que "Sexo" me sale subrayado en rojo y me muestra el error:

> Nombre de columna no valido.

Este es mi código:

```
INSERT INTO DtsPaciente (Nombre, Identificacion, Edad, Sexo, Aseguradora)
VALUES('Nombre','Identificacion','Edad','Sexo','Aseguradora');
```

De antemano agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: Necesitaremos las definiciones de tus tablas. Puedes hacer un [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) donde pones la definición de tus tablas, y la sentencia sql para insertar. Así será MUCHÍSIMO más fácil ayudarte. A como está tu pregunta redactada, no podremos ayudarte tanto ya que no sabemos la definición de tus tablas

Comment: Buen día. Como hago para ver el código de mi tabla?, para poder subirlo. y como se podrá imaginar estoy aprendiendo y se poco y nada.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! bueno.. los errores son clarisimos no? la columna sexo no existe.. e identificacion tiene que ser un numero.. que mas queres que hagamos?